# Ajax call not updating list unless another call to the server is fired

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a ajax call that update a kendo multiselect's data source based on another dropdown's selection, the multiselect also has a read action that filters on the data.

**ajax call**

```
function getPsychiatrists() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/CommonJsonActions/GetPsychiatrists",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {

            var ddlData = $ddlExplainingPractitioner.data("kendoMultiSelect");
            var resultData = [];
            $.each(result, function (k, v) {
                resultData.push({ MemberId: v.MemberId, DisplayName: v.DisplayName });
            });

            ddlData.dataTextField = "DisplayName";
            ddlData.dataValueField = "MemberId";
            ddlData.dataSource.data(resultData);
        }
    })
}
```

**kendo multiselect**

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.ExplainingPractitionerId)
    .Name("ExplainingPractitionerId")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" })
    .MinLength(2)
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
    .Placeholder("Select Explaining Practitioner...")
    .AutoBind(false)
    .Animation(false)
    .MaxSelectedItems(1)
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetMembersByMemberTypeIds", "CommonJsonActions");
        });
    })
    .DataValueField("MemberId")
    .DataTextField("DisplayName")
    .BindTo(Model.ExplainingPractitioners)
    .Value(Model.ExplainingPractitioners)
    )
```

The issue I'm having is, the ajax fire up just fine, however it is not updating the multiselect's data unless there's a input to the multiselect, which triggers a call **GetMembersByMemberTypeIds** to the server. Only after that has happened, the multiselect's data will be updated when the next ajax call is fired. Is there something I can do in the jquery that would mimic that behavior or any other suggestions?

**Edit** It only happens when **ExplainingPractitioners** was assigned (found) during the page loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
ddlData.dataSource.data(resultData);
```

to this:

```
ddlData.setDataSource(new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: resultData }));
```

That should rebind the control immediately with the new data.

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect/methods/setdatasource